# Not able to change color of BMGlyphLabel in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

According to the [BMGlyph](https://github.com/tapouillo/BMGlyphLabel) library, you can change the label color by doing:

```
self.label.color = UIColor(...)
```

The font I created using bmGlyph has a 1px black stroke with a white background.

Using SKACtion.colorizeWithColor() isn't an option since it doesn't work. Already tested it. Is not like any normal SKSpriteNode.

I just wanted to change the label color depending on the user's score.
This is my code:

```
            var color = UIColor.whiteColor()

            if self.score > 10 {
                color = getUIColor(153, g: 185, b: 152, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 40 {
                color = getUIColor(156, g: 151, b: 217, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 60 {
                color = getUIColor(127, g: 191, b: 217, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 80 {
                color = getUIColor(232, g: 121, b: 198, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 100 {
                color = getUIColor(232, g: 74, b: 95, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 120 {
                color = getUIColor(125, g: 227, b: 179, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 150 {
                color = getUIColor(152, g: 226, b: 90, a: 1)
            }else if self.score > 200 {
                let redRand = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))
                let greenRand = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))
                let blueRand = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))
                color = getUIColor(redRand, g: greenRand, b: blueRand, a: 1)
            }

            self.scoreLabel.color = color
```

Any solution for this? I would like to keep my 1px border font.

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to change the font color?

Comment: yes, the white background.. is it possible to change it? or am i stucked with the white forever unless i create 20 different color fonts for the same thing? if that's the case, this is the worst library ever haha

Comment: looks like it is taking a texture and turning it into a sprite node, my guess anyway.  Make sure that you set your `colorBlendFactor` to 1,  there is a bug in sprite kit so you need to explicitly call this to ensure you are getting the blend factor you want

Comment: lol you were correct! i just set the scoreLabel.colorBlendFactor = 1 and worked like a charm! thank you sir! put it as an answer and i will choose it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with sprite kit that will change the `colorBlendFactor` when certain things happen  (Like having a default alpha of 0 will change it to 0 for some reason)  Make sure you explicitly set the value whenever you want to make color alterations.